# Correct planar projection for geopandas.sjoin_nearest for Continental USA?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I have a set of lat/long points that I want to match with the nearest polygon. I import the polygon shapefiles into a geopandas dataframe. I am trying to join this data geopandas.sjoin_nearest.

What is the correct planar projection for this operation for the continental USA? How do I get the distance_col in meters?